# Wireless Shutter Release Remote does autofocus before taking the snap?

Tags: autofocus, remote, nikon-d3000

I have Nikon D3000 and a wireless remote for it. I'm not sure about this thing:

Suppose, I am keeping the camera on tripod where some birds will come. Then, I am setting my required zoom and other parameters except focus. (Note: My lens has autofocus motor) I also set the focus point also where to focus during taking the snap. But I am not sure exactly at which distance the bird will sit. OK, then when I see bird, I press my remote. Is it going to focus correctly for me if the bird is in focal length range and within the focus point?

If wireless doesn't work, I'll buy some wired remote also so that I can take this type snaps if I get the auto focus ensured. Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the camera will AF if you have it in a mode that will AF when you press the button. It's a remote button. That's all.

I found with my remote it more annoying that if would AF so put it manual mode so it would not focus hunt. But I was not take bird photos but photos at night where there was not enough light to AF.